# Redmine: Docker failures

Tags: docker, redmine

I want to install Redmine in Docker. I followed [this](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine) tutorial. When I tried with `Postresql`

```
docker run --name=postgresql-redmine -d \
  --env='DB_NAME=redmine_production' \
  --env='DB_USER=redmine' --env='DB_PASS=password' \
  --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql \
  sameersbn/postgresql:9.6-2

docker run --name=redmine -d \
  --link=postgresql-redmine:postgresql --publish=10083:80 \
  --env='REDMINE_PORT=10083' \
  --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/redmine:/home/redmine/data \
  sameersbn/redmine:3.3.2-1
```

I got the following error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running
>   container: /postgresql-redmine AS /redmine/postgresql-redmine.

And when I try with `MySQL`:

```
docker run --name=mysql-redmine -d \
  --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
  sameersbn/mysql:latest

docker run --name=redmine -it --rm \
  --env='DB_ADAPTER=mysql2' \
  --env='DB_HOST=192.168.1.100' --env='DB_NAME=redmine_production' \
  --env='DB_USER=redmine' --env='DB_PASS=password' \
  --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/redmine:/home/redmine/data \
  sameersbn/redmine:3.3.2-1
```

I don't get error message, but I can't reach it (not in port 3000 and not in port 10083, too)

What's missing?

**EDIT:**
Output of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
3b0d0631080f        sameersbn/mysql:latest   "/sbin/entrypoint...."   3 hours ago         Exited (1) 3 hours ago
```

Output of `docker logs 3b0d0631080f`

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Comment: You are missing the -p parameter in the second example to forward ports.

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a` after the execution of the first two `docker run` commands? Is the container with the name `postgresql-redmine` running?

Comment: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
3b0d0631080f        sameersbn/mysql:latest   "/sbin/entrypoint...."   3 hours ago         Exited (1) 3 hours ago                       mysql-redmine

Comment: Please edit your original question with such additional information. It is much more readable if it is formatted. Looks like the container failed to start. Container logs can be interesting too: `docker logs 3b0d0631080f`

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: This could be a platform issue. Which OS do you use?

Comment: I use Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi has the ARM architecture. Therefore you can't use "normal" images. I am new to this topic, but this [blog post](http://blog.alexellis.io/5-things-docker-rpi/) was interesting.

I suppose that it could be possible to build the required docker images on your own by taking the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile) and replacing the base image with a ARM compatible [ubuntu image](https://hub.docker.com/r/armhf/ubuntu/) (`armhf/ubuntu`) one.

If you want to give it a try:

- Download the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile)
- Replace `FROM sameersbn/ubuntu:14.04.20170123` with `FROM armhf/ubuntu`
- Run `docker build .` in the folder of the edited Dockerfile

This is only guessing, but I am interested if it works.

Comment: Nope. I can launch PG 9.6 on raspbian just fine and it runs just fine. If I have my own image built from a Dockerfile which **only has** `FROM postgres:9.6`, then this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

coz I prefer to work with docker-compose files, here is m working config - just put it into the `docker-compose.yml` file and then run `docker-compose up`. PS: note there are mapped volumes (folders) for plugins, themes, files and db data. I'm using this image for Redmine development and it works very well.

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  redmine:
    image: redmine:passenger
    container_name: redmine
    volumes:
      - ./redmine/plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins
      - ./redmine/themes:/usr/src/redmine/public/themes
      - ./redmine/files:/usr/src/redmine/files
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: db_password
      REDMINE_PLUGINS_MIGRATE: 1

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: redmine-db
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: db_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
```

If you need more info, I can help :)